# Simple Javascript timed counter

Tags: javascript, timer

I am doing the following:

```
function countUp(c){
  c.value = c.value + 1;
  $('#number').text(c.value);
}

var counter = {value: 0};

window.setTimeout(countUp(counter), 100);
```

For some reason the value of my counter seems to always stay 1. I tried using an object instead of a variable because it was my understanding that objects are passed by reference, not value, and I hoped I could change this value through my countUp function.

It's clearly not working, what's wrong?

Here is a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/akmur/pen/WbKGae)

Comment: Is there a reason you are making counter a class with a value property, instead of just as a normal var: ie - var counter = 0;

Comment: I might be wrong, but if I simply a variable it seems to not be working. With an object, I can change the object value within my countUp function. I am learning (forever noob) so I might be wrong... Check it in the  codepen link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `setInterval`.  `setTimeout` is a one-shot deal.

```
setInterval(function () {
  countUp(counter)
}, 100);
```

Comment: Put your function call into an actual function as well.  Edited my post.

Comment: Super, thanks!, I'll choose your answer in 10 minutes :)